# Any suggestion on How to convert swagger yaml file (Only definition part) into XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, swagger

I have tried with python swagger `YAML -> JSON -> XML`. But not able to convert to the schema. It would be a great help if you suggest the methods or tools regarding the same.

Comment: They are not equivalent. You could probably do this. SWAGGER -> code (eg c# using swaggerhub for example) -> Take just the code models -> use xsd.exe to convert to XSD.

Answer (score 0):

Swagger and XSD describe different things, although there is some overlap.

XSD (XML Schema) is a language that describes XML data structures.
Swagger defines REST APIs. It includes a language that describes JSON data structures (JSON schema).

You could extract *only* the model definitions (JSON Schema) from the Swagger and translate those to the equivalent XML Schema. You may find that some of the JSON Schema constructs are difficult or impossible to represent in XSD, but most of them will be OK. You will never be able to translate the resources (paths and operations) from the Swagger because the XSD language has no equivalent concepts.